# Presign transaction + list for sale using OpenSea's SDK createSellOrder method

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'm looking to create NFTs using OpenSea's platform but not list them for sale, then presign a transaction with the wallet that created that NFT using web3 (not entirely sure if this is doable), and eventually use OpenSea's `createSellOrder` SDK method to publish it without having to sign the transaction (given it has been presigned already). Is something like this doable?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible. I just did it using that API on Opensea. The way you sign the TX is by importing a wallet provider. Within that wallet provider you provide your wallet menumonic. The mneumonic lets the provider sign transactions for your wallet. Then using OpenSea's API you can call `createSellOrder` and set the `listingTime` parameter to start the NFT sale at a specific date in the future, and the presigned TX is good to go. Here's an example from Opensea https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/3acbd744425c9136899cd105df9591f84f9cea88/scripts/sell.js

A useful thing to know: you'll need to use the `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` package instead of the wallet provider `@0x/subproviders` that's in Opensea's example because it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for reviving this. Absolutely, this is doable, the only downside is needing the wallet's mnemonic, which could be a security risk if implemented poorly. At the end of the day I ended up using smart contracts and directly calling methods within that contract to put NFTs for sale.